# How to store values in MONGO DB using JAVA?

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb, mongo-java, database

I want to make a **blog post** in my web application. Initially I was using **mysql** as DB. In which i will get the post entered in the **text area of blog** as an object in JS and send that object to java server side. There I will write mysql query and **get the object in resultset and save in database**. But now i want to use mongoDB for the same. I am able to understand the basic stuff through many tutorials which I learnt. But I am unable to implement that in my application. I want to know how the **object** that comes from the **JS** will be sent **inside the loop** and how I should query to **save the object** also similarly if I need to send a object from server side to JS. How should i do.?

**My Server side code:**

```
    public DB MongoConnection(Blog blog) throws UnknownHostException, MongoException{
    Mongo m = new Mongo("localhost" , 27017); //mongo object
    DB db = m.getDB("myblog");
    System.out.println("Connected");
    //making a collection object which is table when compared to sql
    DBCollection items = db.getCollection("items"); 
    System.out.println("items got");

   //to work with document we need basicDbObject        
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    System.out.println("Created mongoObject");

      //Cursor, which is like rs in sql
    DBCursor cursor = items.find();
    System.out.println("items got");
     while(cursor.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }
```

In the above code i understood everything such as how a mongo connection, documents, collections and cursor's work. Now how should i save the value coming as an object from JS and save in mongoDB. Any Suggestions Please?

Comment: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial

Comment: @williams thanks I went through this tutorial before. my question is I am not able to compare this with mysql and implement it. i donot know how to implement. If i am vague sorry for that, just i wanted to explain my situation.I am a newbie trying to go forward. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use method [save](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#save%28com.mongodb.DBObject%29) of DBCollection class something like that:

```
while(cursor.hasNext()){
    DBObject doc = cursor.next();

    doc.put("name", "Leo-vin");

    items.save(doc);
}
```

method cursor.next() returns object of type DBObject. It is your BSONObject.

**Update:**

to modify document (BSON) use method put of class BSONObject

Comment: @Edward thanks. my object blog comes from js. is that object is obj in your answer or what? Please i am confused chnage your obj means How I should change? can you say in words.I wish to understand things and do.so pl can you explain.

Comment: MongoDB does not store records like relative dbs. It stores documents;)

Comment: @Leo-vin, i changed obj to doc. It will be more understandable to read;

Comment: @Leo-vin, i think that as first step you can try to convert your tables into BSON docs. It is not very "true" conversion, but it can work! So, one table's record -> one bson document. Sorry! I can't help in such conversion because i do not have experience with relational databases;)

Comment: @edward thanks I am trying it. Thanks for your help. its very useful